# Syntax error when declaring array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to declare an array in java as part of a tic-tac-toe game, but I get  syntax error when I do this:

```
package tictactoe;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public String a[] = new String[9];

a[0]="";

public class Board {
```

I thought this was the correct way to declare an array, and all the examples I look at confirm it, so why do I get a syntax error?

Comment: also you are declaring array wrong way. It should be like `public String[] a = new String[9];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the declaration of your array inside your class.

You also need to put the assignment of the array inside a method (inside your class). You could also place the assignment in the constructor.

So your code would look something like this:

```
package tictactoe;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Board {
    public String[] a = new String[9];

    public Board() {
        a[0] = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are tring to declear variable outside of class body that's not correct.
you should move your array definition inside of class and initilize it in class constructor (for example).

```
public class Board {
public String a[] = new String[9];

public Board() {
    a[0] = "";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In java, everything has to be inside a class. You cant leave it outside the class and initialize it inside the constructor to make look more clean.

```
public class Board {
public String a[] = new String[9];
  Board(){
    a[0]=" ";
  }
}
```

If you want to see the value initialized, then

```
public class Board {
public static String a[] = new String[9];
  Board(){
    a[0]=" ";
  }
  public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(" Initialially :"+a[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have, and it says "{ expected" instead of ";" at the end of the declaration. Why is that?

Comment: Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

Everything (except the import statements) in Java **MUST** be inside a class. Then you need to write your code to be executed inside a method. Your declaration of an array outside a class has no meaning, because that way it's not a member of any class.

Java is not a scripting language. You cannot write code outside a class.

```
package tictactoe;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Board {
    public String a[] = new String[9];
    //methods here
}
```